# Increment with button when selected SWIFT/XCODE

Tags: swift, xcode, button

I am trying to make my own keypad in XCODE, with SWIFT and ViewController.

I have a label and few separate buttons with their action functions. If I press on one button I would like the label to change to corresponding number, but if I click the button again I want the label to display the number again, not just once but how many times the button is clicked..

**For example:**

Button: Clicked once

Label = 'Hello'

Button: clicked again

Label = 'HelloHello'

Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet var textLabel: UILabel!

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func noOne(_ sender: UIButton) {
        textLabel.text = "1"
        
    }
```

.... Any tips?

Comment: `textLabel.text += "1"`

Comment: @Pancho Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like

```
@IBAction func noOne(_ sender: UIButton) {
    textLabel.text += "1"    
}
```

Or even you can make your method more generic and handle all button clicks in a single method. Link all button actions to a single `IBAction` like

```
@IBAction func onClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
    textLabel.text += sender.titleLabel?.text ?? ""   
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Comment: If I want to decrement with a delete button, the outputs that are in the label? Do I change to -=?